# gfortran LAPACK "undefined reference" error

Tags: ubuntu, fortran, gfortran, lapack

I installed LAPACK on Ubuntu by following [the instruction](http://faculty.washington.edu/rjl/uwamath583s11/sphinx/_build/html/lapack_install.html),

```
sudo apt-get install liblapack-dev
```

thus I can find `/usr/lib/libblas/libblas.a` and `/usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.a`, and then tested it in `gfortran` with the [`randomsys1` example](http://faculty.washington.edu/rjl/uwamath583s11/sphinx/_build/html/lapack_examples.html),

```
  gfortran -llapack -lblas randomsys1.f90
  gfortran -llapack -L/usr/lib/lapack -lblas -L/usr/lib/libblas randomsys1.f90
```

but I received the following errors (`dgesv` is a LAPACK routine):

```
/tmp/ccnzuuiY.o: In function `MAIN__':
randomsys1.f90:(.text+0xb): undefined reference to `init_random_seed_'
randomsys1.f90:(.text+0x3c2): undefined reference to `dgesv_'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Is there anything wrong to install LAPACK? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try to put the link commands (that is, -llapack -lblas) *after* the name of the file you're trying to compile. Otherwise the linker might try to resolve symbols in the wrong order.

Answer (score 6):

See the [gcc/gfortran documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html):

> `-llibrary`,
>   `-l library`
>
> Search the library named library when linking. (The second alternative with the library as a separate argument is only for POSIX
>   compliance and is not recommended.)
>
> It makes a difference where in the command you write this option; the linker searches and processes libraries and object files in the
>   order they are specified. Thus, ‘foo.o -lz bar.o’ searches library ‘z’
>   after file foo.o but before bar.o. If bar.o refers to functions in
>   ‘z’, those functions may not be loaded.
>
> The linker searches a standard list of directories for the library, which is actually a file named liblibrary.a. The linker then
>   uses this file as if it had been specified precisely by name.
>
> The directories searched include several standard system directories plus any that you specify with -L.
>
> Normally the files found this way are library files—archive files whose members are object files. The linker handles an archive file by
>   scanning through it for members which define symbols that have so far
>   been referenced but not defined. But if the file that is found is an
>   ordinary object file, it is linked in the usual fashion. The only
>   difference between using an -l option and specifying a file name is
>   that -l surrounds library with ‘lib’ and ‘.a’ and searches several
>   directories.

So you have to put first the `-L/directory/of/the/library` so the compiler is aware of the directory containing your library, and *then* the `-llibrary` flag.

Comment: Thanks @MBR! The problem was solved by @janneb's comment above.