# Error in linking gfortran to LAPACK and BLAS

Tags: fortran, gfortran, lapack, blas

I have installed LAPACK and BLAS from Synaptic package manager in Ubuntu.

```
whereis libblas
libblas: /usr/lib/libblas.so /usr/lib/libblas.a /usr/lib/libblas

whereis liblapack
liblapack: /usr/lib/liblapack.a /usr/lib/liblapack.so
```

When I try to compile the [randomsys1 example](http://faculty.washington.edu/rjl/uwamath583s11/sphinx/_build/html/lapack_examples.html) with `gfortran` I get the following error messages.

```
gfortran randomsys1.f90 -L/usr/lib/lapack -llapack -L/usr/lib/libblas -lblas
/tmp/cclwtifh.o: In function `MAIN__':
randomsys1.f90:(.text+0x12): undefined reference to `init_random_seed_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

or

```
gfortran randomsys1.f90 -llapack -lblas
/tmp/ccB1isEC.o: In function `MAIN__':
randomsys1.f90:(.text+0x12): undefined reference to `init_random_seed_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

As per my understanding, it is the recommended way to link `gfortran` with `lapack` and `blas` (kindly refer to [gfortran LAPACK “undefined reference” error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20669410/gfortran-lapack-undefined-reference-error?answertab=active#tab-top)). Thanks in advance for pointing out the correct way to compile the `fortran` code using `gfortran`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give this a try

```
gfortran randomsys1.f90 -L/usr/lib -llapack -L/usr/lib -lblas
```

I think you went one directory too far

I wrote a program using the LAPACK eigensolver and here is how I successfully compiled it on my own computer.  It was used to calculate modes of a spring-mass system.

```
gfortran eigen.f90 -L/usr/local/lib -lblas -L/usr/local/lib -llapack
```

This also works on my computer

```
gfortran eigen.f90 -lblas -llapack
```

I just tried both to verify.

PS, now that you know how to compile, I think you need the subroutine init_random_seed in your program (goes after "contains" but before "end program").  This one is from google.  No idea if it is what you need, your professor should be able to steer you correctly here.

```
! Initialize the random number generator using current time,
! so a new sequence of random numbers is generated each 
! execution time.

! Taken from http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/RANDOM_005fSEED.html

    SUBROUTINE init_random_seed()
        INTEGER :: i, n, clock
        INTEGER, DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: seed

        CALL RANDOM_SEED(size = n)
        ALLOCATE(seed(n))

        CALL SYSTEM_CLOCK(COUNT=clock)

        seed = clock + 37 * (/ (i - 1, i = 1, n) /)
        CALL RANDOM_SEED(PUT = seed)

        print *, "Using random seed = ", seed
        print *, " "

        DEALLOCATE(seed)
    END SUBROUTINE
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You have rightly pointed out that `init_random_seed` subroutine was missing. After including the subroutine you provided, I could compile it with the command `gfortran randomsys1.f90 -lblas -llapack`.

Comment: The code does not seem to match what is now in https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/RANDOM_005fSEED.html, maybe there has been an update?

Comment: @Rajarshi, can you officially accept my answer (top left of answer)? I am on a mission for more points!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I followed the recommendation above and
it worked. Here's my working example batch file (it has to be executed 
in the cmd window):

```
gfortran -c for\kurs_evd.f90
gfortran -o kurs_evd.exe kurs_evd.o charint.o -L/usr/lib -llapack -L/usr/lib -lblas
kurs_evd.exe
```